# ps -ef COMMAND NOT FOUND shell script

Tags: linux, shell, centos

When I run the command
`ps -ef | grep -i this | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'` in my terminal, it gives me the correct output which gives me the PID that I need from 'this' service.

But when I try to place it in a shell script variable
`PID=ps -ef | grep stress | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'` 
and try to run the script, the output is `line 9: -ef: command not found`

Help!

Comment: No need for grep and head.  Simpler is `PID=$(ps -ef |awk '/stress/ {print $2; exit}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the output of the ps command read into the variable PID, you will need to use $() and so:

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep stress | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
```